# Excel 2010 Convert range to HTML

Tags: excel, excel-2010

Trying to take a table i have on Excel 2010 and convert it to HTML. Was wondering if this can be done with VBA, and if i could have it spit out a code in a desired cell for easy copy & paste abilities.

The table it would be converting would have formulas in it to automatically pull info from other pages to build it.

Comment: I'm sure it can be done. Do you have an attempt at code?

Comment: For instance, there's this: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/15316/Excel-to-HTML-Macro

Comment: You can spit it out as a simple table or as screenshot, you can take the formatting or have a default layout. If you want a dynamically refreshing one you can develop a relevant formula in VBA. Unfortunately your toolset will hardly cater for the task without VBA though.

Comment: I do have the code i'm trying to basically have excel "rewrite" each time. The Work sheet i use has a bunch of formulas and VBA codes to automatically pull the info i need and apply it to the fields i am working in for copy and pasting.

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/LGyzi.png Is a screen shot of my logs and on the left, the table im trying to apply it to.

Comment: The table i built automatically changes as i click around in my inventory sheet. If i click on the desired drive, it will apply the information i want to an exact copy of the Description i use on sixbit. I want to then take what the table says, and spit out an html code to paste into the Description.

Comment: I answered this question on another page.
http://superuser.com/questions/932631/excel-convert-range-to-html-excel-2010

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I figured out a way around this. Instead of using a vba code to convert a selected range to html, i went an alternate route using formulas and one single vba code.

First thing i did was make a Sheet5, then i took the raw html data from the table i was trying to replicate and divided it up putting breaks in the code were i would enter the new information. I took each chunk and pasted it in A2-K2. Then i took the information that i manually change and linked that to my book in A4-K4. (These are using links to cells on my Log page that change with each listing i do)

In Cell L2, i put the formula  `=CONCATENATE(A2,A4,B2,B4,C2,"&nbsp;",C4,D2,"&nbsp;",D4,E2,"&nbsp;",E4,F2,"&nbsp;",F4,G2,"&nbsp;",G4,H2,"&nbsp;",H4,I2,"&nbsp;",I4,J2,"&nbsp;",J4,K2)`

This took each chunk of raw html and the information from my log and combined it showing a full html code. In cell C11 of my Log sheet, i put `=Sheet5!$L$2` to show the html data on my main page to copy and paste the value.

After this, i noticed excel would add double quotes to everything that was already quoted, and single quotes to other areas. After doing some searching, i found a code that would copy the values of a selected cell so i would be able to paste the html code without quotes. Here's the Macro i used for that.

```
Sub CopyCellContents()
Range("C11").Select
'create a reference in the VBE to Microsft Forms 2.0 Lib
Dim objData As New DataObject
Dim strTemp As String
strTemp = ActiveCell.Value
objData.SetText (strTemp)
objData.PutInClipboard
End Sub`
```

I ran into a problem with User defined data. To solve this, i had to exit the code debugger, reopen the module with the macro in it, go to Tools < References then browse and type `FM20.DLL` into "File name:". Otherwise i could not find the *Microsoft Forms 2.0 Object Library* in the available references.
I used Chip Pearsons site for the macro. cpearson.com/excel/Clipboard.aspx

I assigned this to a button next to cell C11 and now when i click it, the code is copied to my clipboard without quotes. This doesn't work exactly how i was originally planning, but the outcome is exactly what i wanted. Thank you for the help, hope this helps some others.

Here's some screen shots of what i accomplished.

This is were i needed the code for each listing. and Sheet5 is the raw data broken up into cells.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/ATT1q.png

Here's the finished product created by these formulas. And there is my log page with the button. When clicked, it copies the code in the box to the right without quotes.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/jh34N.png

The whole spread sheet is a master piece of mine that is ever growing with different formulas, macros, codes, etc...